# How can I properly execute combo box dependency?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

Im having trouble, I have two combo boxes and I want it so that
cbeat would add the following states in the combo box cbtype, 
the only problem is that after playing with the code for a while the 
combobox type goes blank.

```
    Private Sub cboeat_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboeat.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboeat.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
            cbtype.Items.Add("Manhattan")
            cbtype.Items.Add("Staten Island")
        ElseIf cboeat.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
            cbtype.Items.Add("Queens")
            cbtype.Items.Add("Brooklyn")
            cbtype.Items.Add("Manhattan")
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
        ElseIf cboeat.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
            cbtype.Items.Add("Queens")
            cbtype.Items.Add("Manhattan")
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
        ElseIf cboeat.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
            cbtype.Items.Add("Manhattan")
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
        Else
            cbtype.Items.Clear()
            cbtype.Items.Add("New Jersey")
            cbtype.Items.Add("Manhattan")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are clearing the items after adding them for indexes 1, 2 & 3. Only the first and last options add items that would persist.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling the Clear() method two times in some cases? Maybe this causes the issue.